# MySQL Search Match Against Integer in Search Term

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Where using the following query to search a database of products. Its used in our backend to find products to edit, the follow search term and query works fine.

**Search term:** euro grade

```
SELECT * FROM product_descriptions WHERE MATCH(product_name) AGAINST('"+euro* +grade*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10
```

Output:

```
product id    product_name       price
1             Euro Grade 20k     200.00
2             Euro Grade 30k     300.00
3             Euro Grade 40k     400.00
```

However if we want to search with a integer in the search query it returns no results

**Search term:** euro grade 40k

```
SELECT * FROM product_descriptions WHERE MATCH(product_name) AGAINST('"+euro* +grade* +40k*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It would be good to see some of the sample data you expect to be returned.

Comment: @JonTaylor updated with the output given on first query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably the system variable `ft_min_word_len`.  The default for this value is `4` (as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html)), meaning that words of 1, 2, and 3 characters are ignored.  Your word `'40k'` is too short, so it is not even indexed.

You need to change the parameter value and then re-build the index.

Comment: thanks for that, i've set ft_min_word_len = 2;

Run the following query SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len' which returns 2 and also repaired by tables. However dont get results any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

May be issue is due to below limitation in mysql:

Default minimum length of fulltext search is 4 characters. So if you want to search less than 4 character words then you can change the min and max word length with the variables ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len.